# T-SQL convert Rows into Columns Where Column No not Known

Tags: sql-server

I checked a lot of answer for similar questions but I didn't find the right answer.
I have table Employee:
[image]

and another table EmployeeLeave:
[image]

Now I need to convert rows into columns like this:

[image]

Comment: _"Where Column No not Known"_ ? However, search for [`PIVOT`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=SQL.105).aspx).

Comment: "Column No not known" means probably, that the number of columns (count of differen LeaveTypes) is unknow, PIVOT is the right hint, but is tricky if you want to extent this list. Please give some details...

Comment: @Shnugo : the list goes one distinct Employee per row and number of additional  columns will depend on the number of leaves

Comment: Dynamic SQL using Pivot See [prior posts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404348/sql-server-dynamic-pivot-query)

Comment: Google DYNAMIC PIVOT.